# Possible to get additional information from twitter streaming endpoint (e.g. author, # of retweets)?

Tags: python, twitter

Like the title indicates, I'm looking to find more information from the streaming endpoint on twitter.

This is what I get atm;

```
"data": {
        "id": "134.......707",
        "text": "..."
    },
    "matching_rules": [
        {
            "id": 13473....211649,
            "tag": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Can I specify somewhere that I want the author?

I've used twitters sample code as base: `https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/master/Filtered-Stream/filtered_stream.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you explored the Twitter API documentation for filtered stream yet?

You can learn how to get started with this endpoint group quickly with the quick start guide: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/introduction

We also have details on how to request additional fields here:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/using-fields-and-expansions

The API Reference for filtered stream describes all of the parameters and fields that you can use with those endpoints: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/introduction

And finally, we have different pages describing how to pull different types of content, such as [Tweet annotations](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/annotations), [metrics](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/metrics), and [conversation IDs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/conversation-id).

Comment: Thank you so much, after a good nights sleep I did realise it was all there... messed about with auth for so long I'd gone blind lol. Thank you again.